# Display glitch when going from dual monitor to single

Tags: windows-8, display, amd-radeon

I run a dual screen setup from my ATI 7850, one monitor connected via DVI and one via HDMI.

Whenever I just use the DVI screen and have nothing plugged in to the HDMI output, there is a lot of display glitching, and whenever I try to do anything intensive (if you can call playing a YouTube video intensive), the display completely glitches out and becomes a scrambled white mess.

This problem goes away if I uninstall the 7800 series driver and use the Windows basic driver but this is obviously not ideal. I've tried a lot of versions of the driver with no luck.

I am running Windows 8.

Comment: Do you get the same trouble if instead of disconnecting the monitor you just turn it off? What if you go to display settings (or the  card's config) and configure for just one monitor before disconnecting it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely the fact that Windows is still configured for the dual monitor set up. Weather or not the other monitor is plugged in Windows believes it's there. This however creates a problem for the GPU as it attempts to output data to nothing. Since I do not use Windows 8 extensively nor do I have multi-monitor set up I can assist you no further. Good luck on your journey in search of answer I bid you good luck but this is sadly where out paths must part.

Comment: I worked that much out, would be awesome if there was a way for it not to do that.

Comment: Play with your settings.